# Nearest algorithm according to which the humans analyze the data?

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

How do people analyze the data?
Nearest algorithm according to which the humans analyze the data
Can I say that the people group the data similar to the s.link algorithm based on these test cases? 
[image: Case 1]
[image: Case 2]
[image: Case 3]
[image: Case 4]
[image: Case 5]

Comment: Please do *not* make your question useless/empty by editing it all away. If you have a new question, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your figures suggest that **density based clustering** is what your human users wanted.

E.g. DBSCAN.

Answer (score 0):

Elements of Statistical Learning book is useful to understand basic programming and skills. You can also download this books from http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/